# How can make z-index absolute even if there's transformation modifiers on the element?

Tags: html, css, z-index

In my codesnippit I want to make the red circle appear over the black box but under the text. The problem is when I add `transform: translateZ(0px);` to the black box, my `z-index: 2;` CSS on my text doesn't work anymore. I was wondering if there was a way for one thing to appear on top of another even if they are being transformed. like no matter what Z space each element is in I want the text to appear on top of the red circle.

I was wondering if there is something more powerful than `z-index` I can use on the text without adding an extra div or anything.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.black-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateZ(0px);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.black-box p {
  font-size: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.red-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transform: translateX(-40px);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="black-box">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
<div class="red-box"></div>
```

Comment: read the accepted answer of the duplicate until the end

Answer (score 1):

Put the `red-box` class inside the `black-box` class

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.black-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateZ(0px);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.black-box p {
  font-size: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.red-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transform: translateX(-40px);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="black-box">
  <p>hello</p>
  <div class="red-box"></div>
</div>
```